# Spring security

Tags: java, spring-security

Gostaria de saber como configurar o `spring security` para que o mesmo possa ter dois forms de autenticação.

Ao configurar na minha aplicação o mesmo ao subir a aplicação gera o seguinte erro:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**')** is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your  namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
>       at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.checkPathOrder(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:51)
>       at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.validate(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:40)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.afterPropertiesSet(FilterChainProxy.java:151)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
>       ... 22 more

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209962/spring-security-with-multiple-login-pages